# How do I execute a JavaScript code in python using selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, parsing, html-parsing

I try to extract some info through selenium using these:

```
from selenium import webdriver  # $ pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

path = 'C:/Users/Жираслан/Downloads/chromedriver_win32 (1)/chromedriver.exe'
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
result = wd.find_element_by_class_name('wrapper__top_3UDaE')
```

when the code in the web-page's elements are:

```
<div class="wrapper__top_3UDaE">
    <h3>Лидерборд</h3>
    <span class="wrapper__description_nfMmy">...</span>
</div>
```

and after

```
result = wd.find_element_by_class_name('wrapper__top_3UDaE')
result
```

I get the next error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".wrapper__top_3UDaE"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
```

Please, give me a hint on how to implement this correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Is this class name unique and returns only one element? `wrapper__top_3UDaE`

Comment: It has to be so, but anyway otherwise it would return an array

Comment: check if element is inside iframe.

Comment: No, it's not unique

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you give us the `HTML` code for a `div`

```
<div class="wrapper__top_3UDaE">
    <h3>Лидерборд</h3>
    <span class="wrapper__description_nfMmy">...</span>
</div>
```

To get your element, you will need the following imports

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Then, you can use this `xpath`

```
//div[@class='wrapper__top_3UDaE']
```

and you should be able to get your element

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
result = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='wrapper__top_3UDaE']")
```

If your `div` is a button, you can click on your element

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
result = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='wrapper__top_3UDaE']")
result.click()
```

Comment: You know, I got the idea but it doesn't work this way. I have gound some info about Waits. Now I need to find all elements with such an XPath: ```'//span[@class="wrapper__top_3ztMC"]```.                                                                           I use:                  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
 ```element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "wrapper__top_3ztMC"))     ) and ```these returns me only the 1st element but there is a multitude

Comment: You can use elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until( EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "wrapper__top_3ztMC")))